# How to find the privileges and roles granted to a user in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, security, oracle10g, user-accounts

I am using Linux, Oracle10g.
I have created one user called test. and granted create session and select any dictionary permission to the same user.

i also granted sysdba and sysoper roles to the same users.

Now i want to display all the privileges and roles granted to the user. 
I found following query but it shows only create session and select dictionary privileges.

```
select privilege 
from dba_sys_privs 
where grantee='SAMPLE' 
order by 1;
```

please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [Data Dictionary Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/7347/data-dictionary#t=201610091552406899855)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15665

Check USER_SYS_PRIVS, USER_TAB_PRIVS, USER_ROLE_PRIVS tables with these select statements

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS; 
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS; 
SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

Comment: In other words, do `SELECT * FROM` those tables.  Let's not get lazy... I get upset when I don't see code.  Not everyone can read your mind for exact syntax, and documentation links can get moved.

Comment: For the lazy ones out there:

`SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS;`
`SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;`
`SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;`

Comment: if you are a person looking for roles granted to "whatever in the database" like me, `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` won't work for you because: "USER_ROLE_PRIVS describes the roles granted to the current user", like the Oracle documentation says. Instead, you should be looking for information in the `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS` view. ¿Why? Because: "DBA_ROLE_PRIVS describes the roles granted to all users and roles in the database"

Answer (score 89):

In addition to VAV's answer, The first one was most useful in my environment

```
select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME='SAMPLE';
select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS where Grantee = 'SAMPLE';
select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'SAMPLE';
```

Comment: +1 very complete. Put "user" instead of sample to get info on current logged user

Comment: Note: if you're using `dba_XXX_privs`, the column name is `grantee` instead of `username`.

Answer (score 74):

None of the other answers worked for me so I wrote my own solution:

**As of Oracle 11g.**

Replace USER with the desired username

**Granted Roles:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS 
 WHERE GRANTEE = 'USER';
```

**Privileges Granted Directly To User:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS 
 WHERE GRANTEE = 'USER';
```

**Privileges Granted to Role Granted to User:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS  
 WHERE GRANTEE IN (SELECT granted_role 
                     FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS 
                    WHERE GRANTEE = 'USER');
```

**Granted System Privileges:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DBA_SYS_PRIVS 
 WHERE GRANTEE = 'USER';
```

If you want to lookup for the user you are currently connected as, you can replace DBA in the table name with USER and remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's one more to round it out - 
System Privileges Granted to Role Granted to User:

SELECT * 
  FROM DBA_SYS_PRIVS 
  WHERE GRANTEE IN (SELECT granted_role 
                     FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS 
                    WHERE GRANTEE = 'DWMGR');

Comment: This is the actual answer,  USER_ROLE_PRIVS etc is for that logged in user as stated above.

Answer (score 16):

Combining the earlier suggestions to determine your personal permissions (ie 'USER' permissions), then use this:

```
-- your permissions
select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME= USER;
select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS where Grantee = USER;
select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = USER;

-- granted role permissions
select * from ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS where ROLE IN (select granted_role from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME= USER);
select * from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS  where ROLE IN (select granted_role from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME= USER);
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS  where ROLE IN (select granted_role from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME= USER);
```

Comment: Excellent!  This ought to be the real answer!

Comment: I think that this one is the best answer. It works really good for me.

Answer (score 10):

IF privileges are given to a user through some roles, then below SQL can be used

```
select * from ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS where ROLE = 'ROLE_NAME';
select * from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS  where ROLE = 'ROLE_NAME';
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS  where ROLE = 'ROLE_NAME';
```

Comment: very helpful to dig deeper when u have rights provided via roles.. Second query helped me alot to check if one our table access right is provided to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS 
WHERE UPPER(GRANTEE) LIKE '%XYZ%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS 
where role in (
    select granted_role
    from dba_role_privs 
    where granted_role in ('ROLE1','ROLE2')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

always make SQL re-usuable: -:)

```
-- ===================================================
-- &role_name will be "enter value for 'role_name'".
-- Date:  2015 NOV 11.

-- sample code:   define role_name=&role_name
-- sample code:   where role like '%&&role_name%'
-- ===================================================


define role_name=&role_name

select * from ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS where ROLE = '&&role_name';
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS  where ROLE = '&&role_name';


select role, privilege,count(*)
 from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS
where ROLE = '&&role_name'
group by role, privilege
order by role, privilege asc
;
```

Comment: Only checks the `ROLES` group for a given role.  If we're talking reusability, it should 1) loop through the `USER` group and spit out `*` from `USER_ROLE_PRIVS`, `USER_TAB_PRIVS`, and `USER_SYS_PRIVS `, for a given user, then 2) give the roles for the given user that is input (like in ShamrockCS' answer).  I think given the OP's question, it's where we want to know the properties of a given user, not the users with a given role.

Answer (score 0):

The only visible result I was able to understand was first to connect with the user I wanted to get the rights, then with the following query:

```sql
SELECT GRANTEE, PRIVILEGE, TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;
```