# How to assign all the privileges of existing user to new user in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, privileges

I have a user 'abc'. Now I have created new user xyz. Can I assign all privileges of user 'abc' to new user 'xyz' in one go? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In connection to @Littlefoot answer.

you can copy the user privileges from one of the tables in the answer here [How to find the privileges and roles granted to a user in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066408/how-to-find-the-privileges-and-roles-granted-to-a-user-in-oracle/15066503)
for the first user and copy them into a script that will grant the second user the desired privileges. its a bit of a workaround but it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell - no, you can't.

But, you could if you

- created role(s)
- granted privileges to those roles
- grant roles to user `abc`
- then, after creating user `xyz`, you'd just grant those roles to it

If you want to do it "manually", you'll first have to find out what privileges `abc` has, and then grant them to `xyz`.

Where to look at? Dictionary has a wide choice, e.g.

```
SQL> select table_name, substr(comments, 1, 50) || ' ...' comments
  2  From dictionary where lower(table_name) like '%priv%';

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------
ALL_COL_PRIVS                  Grants on columns for which the user is the granto ...
ALL_COL_PRIVS_MADE             Grants on columns for which the user is owner or g ...
ALL_COL_PRIVS_RECD             Grants on columns for which the user, PUBLIC or en ...
ALL_REPGROUP_PRIVILEGES        Information about users who are registered for obj ...
ALL_TAB_PRIVS                  Grants on objects for which the user is the granto ...
ALL_TAB_PRIVS_MADE             User's grants and grants on user's objects ...
ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD             Grants on objects for which the user, PUBLIC or en ...
ALL_XSC_AGGREGATE_PRIVILEGE    All privileges that make up an aggregate privilege ...
ALL_XSC_PRIVILEGE              All mappings of privileges to security classes in  ...
USER_AQ_AGENT_PRIVS             ...
USER_COL_PRIVS                 Grants on columns for which the user is the owner, ...
USER_COL_PRIVS_MADE            All grants on columns of objects owned by the user ...
USER_COL_PRIVS_RECD            Grants on columns for which the user is the grante ...
USER_GOLDENGATE_PRIVILEGES     Details about goldengate privileges ...
USER_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES    User privileges to access network hosts through PL ...
USER_REPGROUP_PRIVILEGES       Information about users who are registered for obj ...
USER_ROLE_PRIVS                Roles granted to current user ...
USER_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP_PRIVS Switch privileges for consumer groups for the user ...
USER_RSRC_MANAGER_SYSTEM_PRIVS system privileges for the resource manager for the ...
USER_SYS_PRIVS                 System privileges granted to current user ...
USER_TAB_PRIVS                 Grants on objects for which the user is the owner, ...
USER_TAB_PRIVS_MADE            All grants on objects owned by the user ...
USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD            Grants on objects for which the user is the grante ...
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES              Grants on columns for which the user is the granto ...
ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS                Roles which are granted to roles ...
ROLE_SYS_PRIVS                 System privileges granted to roles ...
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS                 Table privileges granted to roles ...
SESSION_PRIVS                  Privileges which the user currently has set ...
TABLE_PRIVILEGES               Grants on objects for which the user is the granto ...

29 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS;

Comment: Yes, that's one of possible sources.

Comment: I used this query to know the privileges and i used these privileges also to my user 'xyz' still i am not able to create an object here.

Comment: If you are saying that you can't create a table (for example) when connected as XYZ because of lack of privileges, then this kind of privileges is in **USER_SYS_PRIVS**.